# Getting Following ! ACCESS to my shope/models

Tags: python, django, sqlite, importerror

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Django Framwork/WebCard/Shope/views.py", line 3, in 
    from .models import product
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**
I cant Import or use  product.objects
and get access to product.objects.aLL() funcs
i want to see my models of product

**shope/views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .models import product

    product.objects.all()


    def Index(request):
        return render(request,'Shope/index.html')
    def about(request):
        return render(request,'Shope/about.html')
    def contant(request):
        return HttpResponse('This page is working')
    def tracker(request):
        return HttpResponse('This page is working')
    def search(request):
        return HttpResponse('This page is working')
    def productview(request):
        return HttpResponse('This page is working')
    def checkout(request):
        return HttpResponse('This page is working')    

    # print(product.objects.all())
    # m = django.apps.apps.get_models()
    # print(m)**
```

**Shope\Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
import django.db 
# Create your models here.
class product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_catagory = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_subcatagory = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    product_pricse = models.IntegerField(max_length=50,default=0)
    product_pub_date = models.DateField()
    product_imag = models.ImageField(upload_to='shope/images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
# print(product.objects.all())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGc4O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo at the import. Should be `from .Model import product` if that's the name of your file. Not `from .models import product`

Comment: Looks like a typo at the import. Should be from .Model import product if that's the name of your file. Not from .models import product    Not Work......for me